# Mapview loading in android

Tags: android, android-mapview

Mapview in android normally takes more time to load even when we don't have any overlays. Is there any way we can make this loading faster? If not can we know when it starts and stops rendering map and show some other view till gets loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Normally MapView waits for valid GPS data. It may takes a few minutes. If you don't want to show current location, start it with lat and long set to zero.